# AngularJS - How can I stop re-rendering templates again?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is it possible in AngularJS to avoid rendering the view again?

I have a page where it queries data from database and displays it to the view, but when I navigate to another page, and then, navigate back again. It renders the view again.

Is it possible in AngularJS that it will just retain the rendered view? I don't want to query again the data and re-render the view. I want to show the rendered view immediately without querying the data again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you save or cache your data in a service, you can avoid querying the server each time. Promises are a great way to do this. Consider the following example, which uses the promise returned by `$http` (but you can easily create your own promises with `$q`):

```
app.controller('SomeController', function($scope, dataService) {
  dataService().success(function(data) {
    $scope.myData = data;
  });
});

app.factory('dataService', function($http) {
  var promise = null;

  return function() {
    if (promise) {
      return promise;
    } else {
      promise = $http.get("...");
      return promise;
    }
  };
});
```

Since `promise` is set the first time you call `dataService()`, and the existing `promise` is returned if it already exists, only the first call to `dataService()` will actually make an HTTP call; the rest will use the existing value.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply Brandon. :) That's a good solution but does it render again the view or html? Suppose, we 200 items and we'll display it using ng-repeat. Does it run the ng-repeat again when we visit the page again? Or, angular will give us the previous html view without running the ng-repeat again.

Comment: Yes, it will re-render the view. If your view is based on `ngRoute`, I'm not sure of any way to prevent this. If you're managing your own view, you may be able to use `ngShow`/`ngHide`, but keep in mind that, while your view is loaded, your scope watchers will be firing.

Comment: Yeah! I agree... I think this is why angular cannot display the html view right away again because of these watchers. Thanks again Brandon.